# C# is there a better way of adding an element from a list in another class?

Tags: c#, list, linq, addition

### This is from first class

```
public class Employees
 {
    public int empID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
 }
public class list
{
    static public List<Eployees> _employees = new List<Employees>();

    public List<Employees> GetList()
    {
        return _employees;
    }

    public string fname;
    public void Add()
    {
        int result = _employees.Count(x => x.empID == x.empID);
        int id = result + 1; //auto increment for empID

         _employees.Add(new Employees
        {
            empID = id,
            FirstName = fname
        });
    }
```

---

### and this is from the second class

```
class Class1
{
  public static main void Main(string[] args)
  {
 ManageEmployee();
}

 static void AddEmployees
{
list ll = new list();

Console.WriteLine("Enter FirstName ");
 string name = Console.ReadLine();
 ll.name = name;
 ll.Add();
 string view = Console.ReadLine();

 foreach(var Employees in list._employees)
 {
  Console.WriteLine(Employees.empID + " | " + Employees.FirstName);
 }
 string reset = Console.ReadLine();
 AddEmployees();
 }
}
```

I'm new to C# and basically, what I want to know is there a better way of adding an element to the list? I saw my teacher do something different but I don't get how she did that and I've been searching for a better way of adding

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't name a `class` `list`. That just gets awfully confusing when you start working with code because as you can see in your own usage, where you're creating a `List<Eployees>` within your `list` class.

Comment: Seeing as `AddEmployee` is not defined, I'd say yes, there is a better way than using an undefined method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd name the class holding a single employee with a singular form:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int empID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Then, your class managing the employees I'd name `EmployeesManagement` and I'd force providing the first name in the `Add` method (perhaps providing other properties would also be beneficial):

```
public class EmplyoeesManagement
{
    private List<Employee> _employees = new List<Employee>();

    public List<Employee> GetList()
    {
        return _employees;
    }

    public void Add(string firstName)
    {
        _employees.Add(new Employee { empID = _employees.Select(e => e.empID).Max() + 1, FirstName = firstName });
    }
}
```

Please, note that an ID for new employee is not created based on the number of employees in the list (guess what happens when you remove an employee from the list) but rather on the maximum value already existing there.

Also, think which properties need to be static and public. If there isn't any particular reason for that, make them non-static and private

In your second class I'd use string builder to create the complete list of the existing employees but that's rather an exercise for you.

And please, use indentation, your code looks much neater then.

Comment: Thank you very much I have learned much much more from your answer. Your add method is what I've been wanting to do. I've also added a .DefaultIfEmpty() beside .Max(), so the first entry wouldn't return an error. Thank you for your teachings.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, and I'm glad you're already modifying the code and making it safer. That's the way to go!